# Visual Basic Read HTML to Add to list with Loop

Tags: html, vb.net, loops, listbox, find

I'm making a program that will fetch data from [this website's](http://cosmic-octane-202719.appspot.com/) HTML. This website updates its list every month and sometimes has different items So far, I'm able to pick up 3 different values that being of Helmet, Sticky Grenade, and C4

However when I try to fetch the Armored Vest value, I get another Helmet.
Here is my source code

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim pos1 As Long, pos2 As Long, newitem As String, findstring As String
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://cosmic-octane-202719.appspot.com/")
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim datastream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(datastream)
        Dim strData As String = reader.ReadToEnd

        'Keep getting 7 Helmets
        For currentitem As Integer = 1 To 7
            findstring = "<li><strong"
            pos1 = InStr(strData, findstring)
            pos1 = InStr(pos1 + 1, strData, ">", vbTextCompare)
            pos2 = InStr(pos1 + 1, strData, "</strong></li>", vbTextCompare)

            newitem = strData.Substring(pos1 + findstring.Length - 3, pos2 - pos1 - findstring.Length + 2)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(newitem)
        Next

        'Sticky Grenade
        findstring = "<li>Lethal: <strong"
        pos1 = InStr(strData, findstring)
        pos1 = InStr(pos1 + 1, strData, ">", vbTextCompare)
        pos2 = InStr(pos1 + 1, strData, "</strong></li>", vbTextCompare)

        newitem = strData.Substring(pos1 + findstring.Length - 3, pos2 - pos1 - findstring.Length + 2)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(newitem)

        'C4
        findstring = "<li>Placeable: <strong"
        pos1 = InStr(strData, findstring)
        pos1 = InStr(pos1 + 1, strData, ">", vbTextCompare)
        pos2 = InStr(pos1 + 1, strData, "</strong></li>", vbTextCompare)

        newitem = strData.Substring(pos1 + findstring.Length - 3, pos2 - pos1 - findstring.Length + 2)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(newitem)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The HTML snippet is

```html
<ul class="disc">
  <li><strong>Helmet</strong></li>
  <li><strong>Armored Vest</strong></li>
  <li><strong>Mk. 42</strong> <span class="red">(Reflex + Grip)</span></li>
  <li><strong>Uzi</strong> <span class="red">(Rapid Fire + Extended Clip)</span></li>
  <li><strong>Combat Knife</strong> <span class="red">(Grip)</span></li>
  <li><strong>Fast Reload</strong> <span class="red">(Advanced)</span></li>
  <li><strong>FMJ</strong> <span class="red">(Basic)</span></li>
  <li>Lethal: <strong>Sticky Grenade</strong></li>
  <li>Placeable: <strong>C4</strong></li>
</ul>
```

Outcome:
[7 Helmets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APfuA.png)

I think my problem is that the program is just finding the Helmet line and not continuing to the next line.
How do I make a loop that will find `<li><strong>` on each line and add the text that comes after `<li><strong>` and before `</strong>` into a listbox.
For example

```
<li><strong>Helmet</strong></li> would put Helmet into listbox1.
<li><strong>Armored Vest</strong></li> would put Armored Vest into listbox1.
<li><strong>Mk. 42</strong> <span class="red">(Reflex + Grip)</span></li> would put Mk. 42 into listbox1
```

Other than that, I'm stuck.

Comment: I think it would be much better to use a HTML parser for this... You should look into the _HtmlAgilityPack_.

Comment: Ty, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem using Regular expressions.

```
Dim items As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(strData, "(?<=<li><strong>).*(?=<\/strong)")
For Each match As Match In items
    For Each item As Capture In match.Captures
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item.Value)
    Next
Next
```

And full code is

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim pos1 As Long, pos2 As Long, newitem As String, findstring As String
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://cosmic-octane-202719.appspot.com/")
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim datastream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(datastream)
        Dim strData As String = reader.ReadToEnd
        Dim items As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(strData, "(?<=<li><strong>).*(?=<\/strong)")
        For Each match As Match In items
            For Each item As Capture In match.Captures
                ListBox1.Items.Add(item.Value)
            Next
        Next
        findstring = "<li>Lethal: <strong"
        pos1 = InStr(strData, findstring)
        pos1 = InStr(pos1 + 1, strData, ">", vbTextCompare)
        pos2 = InStr(pos1 + 1, strData, "</strong></li>", vbTextCompare)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(strData.Substring(pos1 + findstring.Length - 3, pos2 - pos1 - findstring.Length + 2))
        findstring = "<li>Placeable: <strong"
        pos1 = InStr(strData, findstring)
        pos1 = InStr(pos1 + 1, strData, ">", vbTextCompare)
        pos2 = InStr(pos1 + 1, strData, "</strong></li>", vbTextCompare)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(strData.Substring(pos1 + findstring.Length - 3, pos2 - pos1 - findstring.Length + 2))
    End Sub
End Class
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAn8N.png)